# Update on row_number, over partitioned (alternative) in mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a table mmdocpositions where I put documents and positions. Positions have been broken and now there are values 2 in each document. It should be Document1 1, Document1 2, Document1 3, Document2 1, Document2 2, etc... But now it is like Document1 2, Document1 2, Document1 2, etc...

I've managed to write SQL script which selects the right result:

```
set @row_number := 0;
SELECT *
from
(SELECT 
    @row_number:=CASE
        WHEN @document_nr = document 
            THEN @row_number + 1
        ELSE 1
    END AS num,
    @document_nr:=document
FROM
    mmdocpositions WHERE document IN (SELECT document FROM mmdocpositions where POSITION='2'  GROUP BY document,POSITION having COUNT(*)>1) ORDER BY document)x
```

| num | @document_nr:=document |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | CE21100044 |
| 2 | CE21100044 |
| 3 | CE21100044 |
| 4 | CE21100044 |
| 1 | CE21100046 |
| 2 | CE21100046 |
| 3 | CE21100046 |
| 4 | CE21100046 |
| 5 | CE21100046 |
| 6 | CE21100046 |
| 1 | DA21100419 |
| 2 | DA21100419 |
| 3 | DA21100419 |
| 4 | DA21100419 |
| 1 | DA21100422 |
| 2 | DA21100422 |
| 3 | DA21100422 |
| 4 | DA21100422 |
| 5 | DA21100422 |
| 6 | DA21100422 |
| 7 | DA21100422 |
| 8 | DA21100422 |
| 9 | DA21100422 |
| 10 | DA21100422 |
| 11 | DA21100422 |
| 12 | DA21100422 |
| 13 | DA21100422 |
| 14 | DA21100422 |
| 15 | DA21100422 |
| 16 | DA21100422 |
| 17 | DA21100422 |

I used this workaround since in MYSQL version there is no row_number and OVER BY PARTITION. Now I've tried to put this into an UPDATE statement:

```
    set @row_number := 0;
    UPDATE mmdocpositions SET POSITION=x.num
FROM
    (SELECT 
        @row_number:=CASE
            WHEN @document_nr = document 
                THEN @row_number + 1
            ELSE 1
        END AS num,
        @document_nr:=document
    FROM
        mmdocpositions WHERE document IN (SELECT document FROM mmdocpositions where POSITION='2'  GROUP BY document,POSITION having COUNT(*)>1) ORDER BY document)x
```

I got SQL syntax error in HEIDISQL. I've tried to rewrite the code but couldn't make it work. I was wondering whether it's even possible to do it that way or I will have to write the procedure. Please help me out hackers!

Comment: Adding some sample data would really you get across the point of your question.

Comment: Thank you, I've added a picture of the select result.

Comment: Plead read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and edit your question to make a full [mre]

Comment: You do not have a syntax error in HEIDISQL. You DO have a syntax error in SQL. The syntax of your [UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html) statement is incorrect.   (the is no `FROM` in that statement)

Comment: I've tried also without FORM and with other variants I've found on the net. No luck. That's why I thought you guys will help me out, I got minus instead on the question :)

Comment: You should not TRY, but you should read the docs. I do even see an example on the link I provided. (see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html#:~:text=Instead%2C%20you%20can%20employ%20a%20multi-table%20update%20in%20which%20the%20subquery%20is%20moved%20into%20the%20list%20of%20tables%20to%20be%20updated%2C%20using%20an%20alias%20to%20reference%20it%20in%20the%20outermost%20WHERE%20clause%2C%20like%20this )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update command should look like this.

you need to join the table then the new rownumber

i joined both tables ON mmdocpositions.id = x.id, as i know nothing about your table, so you must change that so that mysql will connect the correct rows

```
set @row_number := 0;
UPDATE mmdocpositions 
INNER JOIN     (SELECT 
    @row_number:=CASE
        WHEN @document_nr = document 
            THEN @row_number + 1
        ELSE 1
    END AS num,
    @document_nr:=document
FROM
    mmdocpositions WHERE document IN (SELECT document FROM mmdocpositions where POSITION='2'  GROUP BY document,POSITION having COUNT(*)>1) ORDER BY document)x
    ON mmdocpositions.id = x.id
SET POSITION=x.num
```

Comment: You did a really good job there!!! Thank you very much!